# How to configure log4j.properities file in debug mode?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, logging, log4j

```
Logger alog = Logger.getLogger("auditLogger");


alog.debug("to test audit logger in main screen");
```

it is displaying error message like

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.debug

SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "debug".

SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.debug

SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "debug".
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.appender.Customer1audit=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Customer1audit.File=C:\\OpsConsole\\21-05-2013\\IOpsConsole\\logs\\Cus‌​tomer1audit.log
log4j.appender.Customer1audit.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.Customer1audit.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.Customer1audit.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.logger.‌​customer1auditLogger=info,debug,Customer1audit
```

Comment: Please post your code, not a contrived example, and your `log4j.properties` file.

Comment: This might be helpful for you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm

Comment: log4j.appender.Customer1audit=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Customer1audit.File=C:\\OpsConsole\\21-05-2013\\IOpsConsole\\logs\\Customer1audit.log
log4j.appender.Customer1audit.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.Customer1audit.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.Customer1audit.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayoutlog4j.logger.customer1auditLogger=info,debug,Customer1audit

Comment: the above is my log4j.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of a `log4j.properties` logger line is

```
log4j.logger.loggername=LEVEL,appender1,appender2,...
```

(*one* level, followed by zero or more appender names) so this line

```
log4j.logger.‌​customer1auditLogger=info,debug,Customer1audit
```

is configuring a logger named "customer1auditLogger" to log at the level "info" and send its messages to appenders named "debug" and "Customer1audit".  The error message is telling you that you haven't defined an appender named "debug".

The thing you need to understand is that the log level you specify for a logger is a minimum - it will log all messages at this specified level *or any higher level*.  So you just need to set the level to debug and you will automatically get info (and warn, error and fatal) messages as well.

```
log4j.logger.‌​customer1auditLogger=DEBUG,Customer1audit
```

If you also have other appenders attached to the root logger then you may also want to set

```
log4j.additivity.customer1auditLogger=false
```

to prevent the `customer1auditLogger` messages from going to the inherited appenders as well as the specific `Customer1audit` appender.

You also need to make sure you're logging to the correct logger.  Your example properties file configures a logger called "customer1auditLogger" but your Java code does `Logger.getLogger("auditLogger")` - you need to change one or other of these so they both match.

Comment: bro.. it is Logger.getLogger("customer1auditLogger" only. I misspelt it.. I have already set the level in properties file with the following statement......    log4j.threshold=DEBUG

Comment: @ANILBABU I've made things a bit more explicit, does that make more sense?